# How to remove one child of a child from inside a group?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have complex 3D object that looks this way:

[] Group

- [] Children

  - [] Children

    - Child 1
    - Child 2
    - Child 3

I need to remove child 2 for example. Here is how I try to it:

```
const child = model.children[0].children[2]
model.remove(child)
```

I tried lots of variations for this code, but nothing didn't work. Please help.

**Update**

I failed in removing objects, but setting visible to false worked well.

```
model.children[0].children[2].visible = false
```

Comment: The array containing Child 2 is not `model` but `model.children[0].children`

Comment: @James console.log says that it's the 3D object

Comment: Is it removing anything at all? Can you log the various pieces of your path (`model.children[0]`, `mode.children[0].children[2]`) to determine if you're headed in the right direction?

Comment: @user1599011
yea, I logged it. At logs everything looks right.

Comment: @James I tried also `const parent = this.model.children[0]` and then `parent.remove(parent.children[2])` but it didn't work

Comment: @MAZ It's hard to tell, but I don't think `this.model.children[0]` is the container for Child 2, rather it's `this.model.children[0].children`.  Try `const child = model.children[0].children[2];`  `model.children[0].children.remove(child);`

Comment: @James it throws error: `model.children[0].children.remove is not a function`

Comment: check my answer it works

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="main"> 
<div>
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
</div>
<button onclick="del(child)">Remove 2-nd element</button>
</div>
<script>
const child = document.getElementById("main").children[0].children[1];
function del(elem) {
elem.remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me(

Comment: Ok wait I am making snippet

Comment: Here. check it out

Comment: thank you for snippet. But we're talking about ThreeJS and 3D object imported from gbl file. Everything is happens at canvas and thing works a bit differently than at HTML.